# Custom Action with regsvr

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I would like to run a custom action on a **dll** during my installation process.
There is no clean description that I found. So how would you implement this command:

```
regsvr32.exe /c /n /i:"[PathToIncFolder]" "[BIN]MyFile.dll"
```

in Wix during the Installation or maybe degister during uninstall?

Answer (score 0):

Preferrably not. The recommended way to install COM components nowadays is to manually add the registry entries.

Comment: And what are these entries?? Are they all the same for every com object that I have to register manually??

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should be performing manual registration of the keys and values needed to install the COM component. The reason self-registration is frowned upon is because of problems concerning rollback and uninstall.

The OLE/COM specification should give you information on what keys need to be registered but at a minimum you will need to add a set of entries to a new subkey at HKCR\CLSID\.

Inside this subkey you will need at a minimum, the path to the component and the threading model.

Depending on what your COM component does you may also need to register a PROGID, file-extension maps and APPID.

If the COM object is a managed assembly then your task is slightly different as you need to refer to the .NET bootstrap assembly instead of your own.

If your COM object is written in ATL then your project probably contains a .rgs file which contains all the registry information you'll need.

For further information on COM registry entries check the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678477%28v=vs.85%29).